# Inkscape not terminating when executed via subprocess in Python

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, inkscape

I'm encountering a problem when trying to execute Inkscape via Python's subprocess module. Specifically, I'm attempting to convert a PDF file to SVG using the following command:

```
import subprocess
command = ['inkscape', '--export-type=svg', 'file.pdf']
subprocess.run(command)
```

I've also noticed that the process persists in the task manager even after the script has forzed to finish (without create the svg file).

Could anyone provide insights or suggestions on why this might be happening and how I can resolve it?

Comment: Is this Windows?

Comment: Yes, i'm execute in Windows

Comment: What happens if you run that exact command in a Command Prompt?

Comment: Return the following message `** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:35844): WARNING **: 15:24:21.897: No pages selected, getting first page only` and created sucessfully the svg file

Comment: To quote [the Inkscape command line page](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/Using_the_Command_Line): "To close the GUI automatically at the end of processing, use `--batch-process`." but it sounds more like you ran into a bug that you should file on the [Inkscape issue tracker](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues) with details on exactly what you're doing, using exactly which versions of windows, Inkscape, etc.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I had no the intention of showing the GUI, but when trying with `--batch-process`, inkscape does not create a svg file and never finished the process,  it continues indefinitely.

Comment: Definitely file an issue.